# Java, Including int Variables in Print line

Tags: java

How would you insert a variable in the middle of this sentence where the () are

```
System.out.println("Since there are (trying to insert  int bluerocks here) there must be less than 12 normal rocks  "+bluerocks);
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Since there are " + bluerocks  + " there must be less than 12 normal rocks  ");` or look at `String.format()`

Comment: Look at [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

Comment: Just split the string. Or use a format String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some options.

Either with string concatenation, right in the spot that you want it (mind the number of quotes):

```
System.out.println("Since there are (" + bluerocks
                    + ") there must be less than 12 normal rocks");
```

...or with symbol substitution, via `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("Since there are (%d) there must be less than 12 normal rocks",
                  bluerocks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this several ways, Java supports inline string concatenation, so this is valid:

```
System.out.println("Since there are " + bluerocks + " there must be less than 12 normal rocks  ");
```

or, you could use the `format` method:

```
System.out.format("Since there are %d there must be less than 12 normal rocks  \n", bluerocks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`String` concatenation operator `+`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) and `println()` like

```
System.out.println("Since there are " + bluerocks 
    + " there must be less than 12 normal rocks");
```

Or, with [`printf(String, Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) like

```
System.out.printf("Since there are %d there must be "
    + "less than 12 normal rocks%n", bluerocks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many people here have given you the right answer

```
System.out.println("Since there are " + bluerocks + " there must be less than 12 normal rocks");
```

or

```
System.out.format("Since there are %d there must be less than 12 normal rocks  \n", bluerocks);
```

or

```
System.out.printf("Since there are %d there must be than 12 normal rocks%n", bluerocks);
```

but if that seems to be complicated or difficult then you can always break it down in multiple statements of print

```
System.out.print("Since there are ");
System.out.print(bluerocks);
System.out.print(" there must be less than 12 normal rocks\n");
```

its all about learning, no need to fuss here.